# Why won't maven-antrun-plugin run?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm having trouble getting the antrun plugin to run.

I have this configuration in my pom:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>       
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Hello, maven"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn:compile` it runs but all I see in the logs about the antrun plugin is this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.4:run (default) @ datasite-cms ---
project.artifactId
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

Why isn't the plugin actually doing anything?

Comment: Why do you need to use maven-antrun-plugin? What is the purpose ?

Comment: To run sencha command's build tools from maven.

Comment: Also @khmarbaise, is there some reason why I shouldn't use the antrun plugin?

Comment: I made often the experience that users don't know which plugins exists...which is most of the time simpler than using maven-antrun-plugin...but there exist some situations where you can't avoid maven-antrun-plugin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use an uptodate version of the [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) if you really need to use maven-antrun-plugin.

The [older versions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-antrun-plugin-1.4//examples/tasksAttributes.html) have using the configuration tag: `tasks` instead of `target`. But stop using such ancient versions of Maven plugins.

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I was doing wrong. I didn't even realize that I was using an old version. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The uptodate list of maven plugins can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @khmarbaise I am facing this same task issue, but for me upgrade is not an option as of now. while I trigger the install from command line it fails, but when I run it using intellij maven plugin, it works. Any idea why its failing in command line?